# How to get class used in genericized object

Tags: java, android

I have the following method which expects an object with a parameterized class. Kindly help me find the class of T. For example, i have put a return of JsonObject.class.

```
private static <T> Class<T> getType(me.yoctopus.util.Response<HttpResponse<T>, JSONException> response) {

   /*
    Type type = ((ParameterizedType) response
            .getClass()
            .getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    Type httResponse = ((ParameterizedType) type
            .getClass()
            .getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
   return (Class<T>) httResponse;*/
   return (Class<T>) JSONObject.class;


}
```

I need to determine and return the class T

Comment: Pretty sure you can't do that.

Comment: The caller will need to supply a type token (e.g. `Class<T>`). You can't recover a Class object from a type parameter unless the type is known at compile time, which it isn't here. I'm pretty sure this question is a duplicate but I'm having a hard time finding a good dupe to close it against.

Comment: How about if i change the signature to this `Class<?> getType(me.yoctopus.util.Response<HttpResponse<?>, JSONException> response)`

Comment: Do you want to get generic class or it's name?

Comment: @Yoctopus: It doesn't help because you can't get a `Class` object regardless. Somehow the caller of this code will need to pass an object representing what type it wants to get back.

Comment: @Ejusius: I want to get the T generic of HttpResponse

Comment: @Daniel Pryden: Can i get the object representing what i want back and return its class?

Comment: The response passed as argument is an interface